# Traditional chinese for Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, chinese-locale, language-packs

I already search on Google and CI websites but no luck until now.
Do you know where I can find the traditional chinese language pack for Code Igniter?

PS: I already download CI from the official Taiwanese CI website but it only contains english language files.

Thank you for your help! (or wish me good luck to create this language pack!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the language pack here:

https://github.com/CodeIgniter-TW/CodeIgniter-Language

If you aren't familiar with git, just Click the *Download Zip* button to get an achieve.

Then extract them to codeigniter/system/language/zh_tw/. :)

Comment: actually it's not for the last version, but it's better than nothing!

Comment: Emmmm... Maybe there's not much difference between 2.1.3 and 2.1.1.

Comment: I think yes, I check 4 files and I didn't find any difference.